# Media Queries for Macbook Pro retina

Tags: html, css, media-queries

Is it possible to write different media queries for both 13inch and 15inch Macbook Pro Retina. Ive being trying all sorts of queries but nothing seem to for properly. I'm quite new to development, so if anyone could provide me with two media queries that will work independently for each screen would be highly appreciated.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? dynamic gui's or webpages that adapt to screen size usually accomplish my purposes

Answer (score 2):

Generally speaking it's better to create a desktop style that works for all monitors above a certain size. Instead of targeting specific devices, try specifying a general screen size range. You can still target retina devices separately to serve them higher res images.

```
/* ----------- Non-Retina Screens ----------- */
@media screen 
  and (min-device-width: 1200px) 
  and (max-device-width: 1600px) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1) { 
}

/* ----------- Retina Screens ----------- */
@media screen 
  and (min-device-width: 1200px) 
  and (max-device-width: 1600px) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)
  and (min-resolution: 192dpi) { 
}
```

[See Chris Coyier's guide for more details](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/)

Comment: I'm sorry to say that Ive tried multiple queries but nothing seem to get the styles that I try to write for retina displays. My styles effect globally to all screens which is  a problem for me. Anyways Thank you for your time and effort.

Answer (score 1):

Media queries are filters that can be applied to your CSS. They make it easy to change styles based on the device height, width orientation and resolution.

You can use media queries like:

```
(max-width: 640px)
(min-width: 641px) and (max-width: 800px)
(min-width: 801px) and (max-width: 1024px)
(min-width: 1025px)
```

The last one will apply to all resolutions above 1025px eg.